# Swift: how can I use an 'AnyClass' variable to define what type is inside an array?

Tags: ios, swift

The following code should explain what I want to do reasonably clearly. Of course, this produces a compile time error.

What is the correct way to do what the below code intends?

```
protocol FilterableDataSource {

    var dataClass: AnyClass { get }
    var data: [dataClass.dynamicType] { get }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using generics?

Comment: @titaniumdecoy yes, but I don't know how to do what I am trying to with generics. If you know then please add an answer :)

Comment: Swift is statically typed, so you can't have a property whose type is defined at runtime. You could of course use generics, but note that these are also statically typed by the compiler (e.g. for the different type calls to a generic function).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think this through before I commented.  I don't think generics will help you in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use generics with protocols, but if you try, Swift gives you a hint - associated types. Code rarely explains intent clearly, but I'm guessing what you want to achieve is along the lines of...

```
protocol FilterableDataSource {
    typealias T
    var data: [T] { get }
}

class MyData { }

class MyClass: FilterableDataSource {
    typealias T = MyData
    var data: [MyData] { return [MyData]() }

}

print(MyClass().data.count)
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that now FilterableDataSource cannot be used as a protocol type because it contains a typealias (e.g. let ds: FilterableDataSource = MyClass() does not work), which makes it essentially useless for its intended purpose.

Comment: Which highlights the problem that you have not explained what you want to achieve. The code does implement what you asked for. Now you're adding in new requirements. Why don't you update your question and maybe somebody can help you.

Comment: I didn't ask the question.

Comment: Good point. So maybe it does satisfy the requirement. There is no mention of polymorphism being needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `AnyObject` instead of `AnyClass`. Then you can just cast it into whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't ensure that data always returns the right type of object, and means everywhere this is used, the object type has to be checked. I guess maybe what I am trying to do is not possible

Comment: Have you tried checking for protocol conformance instead of a specific class type?

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you want to do is define a typealias requirement in your protocol.

```
protocol FilterableDataSource 
{    
    typealias DataClass : AnyObject 
    var data: [DataClass] { get }
}

class PersonDataSource:FilterableDataSource
{
   typealias DataClass = Person
   var data[Person]  = []

}
```

So instead of requiring your filterable data sources to devine a variable containing the class, you require them to define a typealias for the elements of the data[] variable.  Ideally your data classes have a common ancestor other than AnyObject which you can use as the typealias restriction.